# Trouble Converting cURL request to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, curl

I don't know what's wrong. I've spent almost an hour reading and re-reading, checking my spelling etc. I was hoping maybe someone can point out what I'm doing wrong.

This is the cURL statement that returns successfully in the terminal:

```
curl https://api.gumroad.com/v2/products \
  -d "access_token=123456abcdef" \
  -X GET
```

The following are some of my attempts that did not work. And yes, I'm certain jQuery has been loaded:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.gumroad.com/v2/products",
    data: "access_token=123456abcdef",
    success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
    }});
```

And this one:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.gumroad.com/v2/products",
    data: "access_token=123456abcdef",
    processData: false,
    type: "get",
    success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
    }});
```

And another one:

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
             xhr.setRequestHeader("access_token", "123456abcdef")
        }, success: function(data){
            alert(data);
            //process the JSON data etc
        }
})
```

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are sending a string instead of a data object, try this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.gumroad.com/v2/products",
  data: {access_token: "123456abcdef"},
  processData: false,
  type: "get",
  success: function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  }
});
```